# Android EditText InputFilter not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I have an `EditText`, accepts chars except whitespace, I use an `InputFilter` to filter the input chars, and a `InputFilter` to constrain the length of the input, but the `InputFilter`s do not all work.

My full code is something like below: `initBodyView()` is the entrance of the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends CustomedActivity{


InputFilter mcFilter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))) {
                // do something
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};


private TextWatcher mcTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mVinLimit <= INPUT_LOWER_LIMIT) {
            mcFlag = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mVinLimit > INPUT_LOWER_LIMIT && mVinLimit < INPUT_UPPER_LIMIT) { 
            if (s.length() == mVinLimit) {
                mcFlag = true;
            } else {
                mcFlag = false; 
            }
        } else if (INPUT_UPPER_LIMIT == mVinLimit) { 
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                mcFlag = true;
            } else {
                mcFlag = false;
            }
        }

    }
};



// the entrance of the activity
@Override
protected void initBodyView() {
    mBodyView = inflate(R.layout.layout);
    mc = (EditText)mBodyView.findViewById(R.id.mc);
    mc.addTextChangedListener(mcTextWatcher);
    mc.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            new InputFilter.LengthFilter(INPUT_LIMIT), mcFilter
    });
}
```

}

**the second `InputFilter` does not work**

the attributes of the `EditText` is as follows:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/carriage_number"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:inputType="textUri"
android:singleLine="true" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: What is ur problem ?

Comment: The mCarriageNumberFilter couln't filter whitespace.

Comment: How is your program flow ?  Is your breakpoint hits  if (Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i)))

Comment: You mean you have to add only character in edittext??

Comment: @DonChakkappan The code never hits the mCarriageNumberFilter

Comment: @Nils Yes, I only allow users input characters.

Comment: Please post your entire code for the Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 4):

The TextWatcher is getting and handling the changes to your EditText
instead of the InputFilter.
Comment out the line below and your code will be okay.

```
//mc.addTextChangedListener(mcTextWatcher);
```

Comment: No, the `TextWatcher` was to set the flag of a button, `InputFilter` could not do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I have solved the problem, the `InputFilter` was reset somewhere, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in xml,

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/carriage_number"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:digits="qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:inputType="textUri"
android:singleLine="true" >
</EditText>
```

enter characters to allow in edittext in,

```
android:digits="qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM"
```

Comment: This directly block users' input without a feedback, it's not qualified for the demand of the product.

Comment: You enter any digits...??

Answer (score 0):

I have found where the problem is, there were someother code reset the `InputFilter`s of the `EditText`, since the project is a team project, I haven't found it, sorry. Thanks for all your help.